# How can I connect to HTTPS using socket?

Tags: python

I know in Python we can use libraries like urllib, requests, etc, to do the job, but I want to know how to do the same using sockets

Thank you!

Comment: All you have to do is re-implement the HTTP + TLS protocols using python libraries

Comment: Helps:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-python/